# How can I get a higher score in Metal Torrent?

Tags: metal-torrent

I was playing Metal Torrent and I noticed that there was an online leaderboard. 
I was ranked in the 6000s. Can anyone give me tips on how to get a higher score, and possibly get a higher rank in the *online ranks*?